# What app is this icon with a square and a black triangle?

Tags: macos, applications

I've seen this icon in a tutorial I watched on YouTube. What app is this icon?
Have searched through Google Images but found nothing.

[image: App Icon]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is the icon for [**AirPlay**](https://www.apple.com/airplay/), by Apple, and that menu bar item allows you to control the streaming/mirroring of content on your Mac to an Apple TV or other AirPlay server.

> #### Turning AirPlay Mirroring on and off
>
> If your Mac supports using your Apple TV as a display, an AirPlay menu appears in the menu bar when an Apple TV is on the same network. The AirPlay Mirroring menu icon turns blue when AirPlay Mirroring is on (<sub>[image]</sub>).
>
> [image]

<sup>Source: [About AirPlay Mirroring in OS X](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201343)</sup>

Comment: As a mnemonic, it's an arrow pointing towards a TV screen.

Answer (score -2):

The little square with the triangle at the bottom is
Part of Crome Cast.

Comment: needs reference

Comment: Your answer seems to be totally wrong.  Can you provide a reference for it? The Chromecast icon has little quarter circles coming from the lower left corner.